# Center spans with bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this html code:

```
<div id="header" class="row-fluid text-center">
    <div class="span1 text-center header">HOME</div>
    <div class="span1 text-center header">PORTFOLIO</div>
    <div class="span1 text-center"><img src="images/logo.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="span1 text-center header">ABOUT</div>
    <div class="span1 text-center header">CONTACT</div>
</div>

<div class="row text-center">
    <img src="images/header.png" />
</div>
```

I wish it to be centred. I tried to work with `offset` class but it is not 100% centred.
[image]

Comment: Can you please paste the Screenshot, so we know that what you exactly want?

Comment: A bootstrap row is made up of 12 even "sections". You have 5 sections inside of it. An odd number is always going to be off-centre using just bootstrap classes, you are going to need to override bootstrap with your own css.

Comment: So is there any work around?

Comment: Yes, I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have 5 elements in your row, you need to offset by 3.5 rather than offset by 3 to make it exactly centered. The best way to do this is to create a custom `offset3-5` class. Here is the code you would need. Also, here is a working fiddle: [Link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jk5en/)

```
HTML
<div class="cont"><div id="header" class="row-fluid text-center">
    <div class="offset3-5 span1 text-center header">HOME</div>
    <div class="span1 text-center header">PORTFOLIO</div>
    <div class="span1 text-center"><img src="images/logo.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="span1 text-center header">ABOUT</div>
    <div class="span1 text-center header">CONTACT</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row text-center">
    <img src="images/header.png" />
</div>

CSS
.row-fluid .offset3-5:first-child
{
    margin-left: 29.166666%;
}
```

[image: Diagram of 12/5]

The 12 black boxes above represent a bootstrap row, and the red boxes represent your 5 boxes. If you had offset 3, it would be slightly to the left. The solution was to make a new offset. To get the correct percentage, I did (3.5/12)*100 to get 29.166. You can make any custom offset you need, by working out how much goes on each side and then doing the same equation, but with that number instead of 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Use Bootstrap's css class pagination-centered like this:

```
<div class="span12 pagination-centered">
    Center content.
</div>
```

Class pagination-centered is already in bootstrap.css

```
 .pagination-centered{text-align:center;}
```

In Bootstrap 2.3.0. use class `text-center`
But it need to use one of the two classes, `row` or `span12` with a `text-align: center`.

DEMO

http://jsfiddle.net/xKSUH/

or

http://jsfiddle.net/xKSUH/1/

You can center it with creating seperate css class:

```
.center {
   margin: 0 auto !important;
   float: none !important;
}
```

DEMO

http://jsfiddle.net/WesWz/9/

Comment: I think that the inner spans that make the problem

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it with a

```
<div class="container">
</div>
```

You will need a fixed width on the parent for it's children to be centered.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div id="header" class="span12 header text-center">
    <div class="">HOME</div>
    <div class="">PORTFOLIO</div>
    <div class=""><img src="images/logo.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="">ABOUT</div>
    <div class="">CONTACT</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is centred now, but looses all bootstrap's fluidness